# Behaviour of Select Feature by Freehand tool in my own plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

I am calling QGIS "Select Feature by Freehand tool" in my plugin. what it will does is it allows the user to select features in mapcanvas and i made a signal like if selection changed in mapcanvas , will display the number of features selected in mapcanvas in a information box.This is what my plugin does. And what i am facing now is even without using the plugin if i select the features using select freehand tool, it does the same job as what my plugin does.Why does this behaviour in QGIS? What is my solution for this?should i not trigger the Select feature by freehand tool in my own plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to connect the SIGNAL `selectionChanged` when your plugin is opened and disconnect it when your plugin is closed.

For example, you could set the connection at the beggining of the `run` method and disconnect it at the end of the `run` method. This way, when your plugin is not running, you won't get QGIS showing the information box you mentioned.